# How to calculate the number of floating point operations a task/ process requires? (not FLOP/s, but FLOP)

Tags: performance, machine-learning

There have been many papers quoting FLOP to quote the performance of a specific approach in machine learning. For example,

> We trained two models with different capacities: BlazePose Full (6.9 MFlop, 3.5M Params) and BlazePose Lite (2.7 MFlop, 1.3M Params).

I assume they measured the number of Mega FLOP needed to run the model on input. **But they did not explain how**.

---

This may be specific to neural networks, but probably isn't. This is not the same question as how to calculate the floating point operations per second a machine is capable of (which there are plenty of answers to).

Comment: If you know the details of your calculations you should be able to count the number of additions (subtractions) and multiplications (divisions) involved. For example, for calculation of the factorial n! you would need (n-1) multiplications. So if n=1e6 that would be 1 MFlop.

Comment: They might have also taken the known values of FLOPs/cycle and cycles/second for a given processor and multiply it with number of cores and time spent. That would give an approximation, but seeing that they 6.9MFLOPs -which is probably also an approximation- this calculation wouldn't be too far away from the truth.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas It is extremely optimistic to assume that this approximation would work. Various operations differ a lot by memory and cache usage, and are going to execute at wildly different FLOP/s speeds.

Comment: perf stat -e <counter> foo.x

Comment: Not all processes use CUDA, but for CUDA applications, we can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812446/a-method-of-counting-floating-point-operations-in-a-c-cuda-program-using-ptx

Comment: For tensorflow, we can use `tf.profiler` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085938/tensorflow-is-there-a-way-to-measure-flops-for-a-model

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32809

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, you are right and I agree that is optimistic because I assume that the processor is never idle. However, they are reporting one significant digit of accuracy i.e. it is likely that there is %5 relative error in their reporting. Assuming they don't dilly-dally sleep(500) in their application, the approximation I suggested would fall into that %5 error range.

Comment: Unfortunately, "FLOPS" is ambiguous. It can be either floating point operations per second, or total number of floating point operations.

Comment: Yes Mark, exactly my title (not FLOP/s, but FLOP)

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I think the convention is as FLOPs being the plural of FLOP and FLOPS being FLOPs/second. There shouldn't be any ambiguity but of course it could be a typo easily.

Comment: BTW, At some point in the 80s, starting with computer manufacturers, and then spreading to the mainstream, FLOPS, either meaning, doubled overnight. It used to be that the combination of one multiplication and one addition constituted one floating point operation. Then, by the magic of sleazy salesmen, it became two operations, and voila, performance doubled.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, wow I didn't know that. I guess it was a good strategy. Afaik, at the time 1 multiplication costed as much as 4 additions (or more if implemented through software) and division costed and still costs multiple cycles. Also I think new Intel CPUs have a fused multiply add instruction which can run at the same speed as a single addition operation. However, I do not know how true that is, maybe you need an Intel compiler and have to toggle some optimizations on to get that. Probably, it is harder to measure the actual number of FLOPs with the old definition.

Answer (score 1):

All processors have counters that can be used to count all sorts of things between a point A in your program, and a point B. Examples are the number of floating point operations performed, the number of branches encountered, the number of cache misses, etc.

I don't know, of course, what the authors of the paper you quote did, but it's not very difficult to actually *count* how many FP operations were performed -- in fact, it's much easier to do that than to estimate how many operations a specific algorithm would have to perform.

Comment: Note that not all counters work correctly on all processors.